# How can i calculate (log) in js for all browsers?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to calculate log3(4) in js . but this method is not supported by all browsers.
so, how can i calculate it in all browsers?

Comment: My first result of `log3(4)` in js is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/log

Comment: Math.log _is_ supported in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Only just via Math.log: `Math.log(4) / Math.log(3)`

Comment: i don't want natural log